# Java resultset max column?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

I'm fairly new to Java and I was wondering how I could get all of the columns of a returned via MySQL query. For instance,

```
SELECT * FROM `login`
```

And then I had this code to return the results:

```
        while (rs.next()) {
            for (byte i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                result = result+" "+rs.getString(i);
            }
        }
```

I want 10 in the for loop to be the maximum number of columns because of dynamic MySQL queries. Is there a simple way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although, as duffymo suggested, it's better to spell out the columns you want to receive in the query, you can use ResultSet metadata to fetch the number of columns returned:

```
 ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
 int numberOfColumns =rsmd.getColumnCount();

 while (rs.next()) {
      for (byte i = 1; i <= numberOfColumns; i++) {
           result = result+" "+rs.getString(i);
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'd limit the fields that are returned. That's a SQL issue, not a Java issue. Change your query to something like this:

```
select this, that, theothercolumn from mytable;
```

Then you can use this to limit it dynamically:

```
rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend not using SELECT *.   If you know the columns you want, spell them out.  It'll make your code more robust in the face of column changes and reduce the number of bytes on the wire.

Comment: what do you exactly mean with "reduce the number of bytes on the wire"?

Comment: If you have 100 columns in the table, and you SELECT *, that means all 100 columns are coming back to your machine for every row, regardless of how many you need.  If that table has a million rows, SELECT * brings them all back whether you need them or not.  It's inefficient to filter them on the client.  Do the filtering in SQL  - the thing that it's good at - and only bring back what you need.

Comment: Ah, ok! For a second I thought that there could have been a difference between accessing a record by its column_number vs its column_name... lol